# SQL Server connection string in code vs config file in ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I already have a connection string in my config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
        name="ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=*;Initial Catalog=*;User ID=*;Password=*"
        providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server" />
```

Currently I am just adding another connection string in my .cs file:

```
SqlConnection myConnection =
    new SqlConnection("user id=*;password=*;server=localhost;");
```

I want to use config file string to connect to a database in the .cs file without adding another string. How can I do that?

```
using (SqlConnection cn =
    new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString()))
```

This was the code I found, is there any shorter way?

Comment: No, no shorter way unless you wrap the retrieval of the connection string in a read-only property in a separate static class or something, giving you `MyConnectionStrings.ConnectionString;` or however you decide to name it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but you could wrap it in its own little helper function:

```
private static string GetConnectionString(string name)
{
    return WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
}

using (var cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString("MyDbConn"))) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
Connection up and running

Answer (score 4):

Using `ConnectionStrings` property of [System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) to get connection string in config file

Comment: @Bhrugesh Patel: If you have only one connection string, then use
`WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString`

Comment: I have actually two.. One is to localhost, another is to actual MS SQL server.. But I will remove localhost once I am done testing

Comment: Then just use **name** instead of **index** which you've found in accepted anwser :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) to get access to the connection string defined in your config file.

```
 var myconnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
      .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static helper class, named Config or something similar and give it a property ConnectionString, that will return the long "WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString" thing. That is the approach I usually go with in my projects and it's actually very easy to use.

```
public static class Config
{
   public static string ConnectionString
   {
      get
      {
         return WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString;
      }
   }
}
```

This approach is the most useful when more classes need to acccess the connection string and this way you have a centralized access to it and easy to change solution.