# How do I retrieve both the server name and database name from a connection string in web.config

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config

How do I retrieve both the Server Name and Database Name from a web.config connection string programatically through the .net api?  Preferably without using an html or xml parser I create.  Looking for the simplest way to retrieve this type of information.
Example web.config snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MyServer;User ID=admind;password=ju7mpst@rterz_Fak3;Initial Catalog=dbDatabase" providerName="System.Data.OLEPlethora"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
```

result:
server=MyServer
database=dbDatabase

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177223/sql-server-connection-string-in-code-vs-config-file-in-asp-net-site) regarding retreiving connection string settings. This appears to be much simplier, however, I'm not sure if I can iterate over many connection string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the connectionstring from config as such:

```
var myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
```

You can then use the [oledb connectionstring builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to parse any connectionstring and extract the relevant parts.

```
var builder = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(myConnectionString);
var servername = builder["Data Source"];
var database = builder["Initial Catalog"];

Console.WriteLine("server={0}, database={1}", servername, database);
```